# why django multivaluedict get returns last element

Tags: python, django, multi-value-dictionary

I have used **Django MultiValueDict** many times and all the times either I use the entire list stored with a key or I want to use the first value from the list. A common use case is use it as form initial data.

My problem is that by default Django MultiValueDict's get method returns last element.

Do I have to override **getitem** of MultiValueDict or is there any better alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
mv_dict.getlist()[index]
```

Where `index` is the index of the element you want in the list. For example `0` to get the first element.

Check https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/datastructures.py#L285

But certainly if for some reason you always want to return the first element of the list, subclassing `MultiValueDict` sounds reasonable. It depends on your use case.

Comment: That's right. But again I have to handle ListIndex error. Actually I am curious about why last element and not first? What is the common use case for last element?

Comment: Answer in source code: _This class exists to solve the irritating problem raised by cgi.parse_qs,
    which returns a list for every key, even though most Web forms submit
    single name-value pairs._